# Need advice on adding items to Shopping Cart

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, database, razor

I'm about to implement a basic shopping cart. I've already done this before, but am looking for a better way.

Basically, the way I had the Table setup before was like this:

MyCart table:

```
UserId     ProductID     Quantity     TotalPrice
06         PID08         1            499.00
06         PID06         2            200.00
06         PID04         1            499.00
06         PID01         1            499.00
06         PID09         1            499.00
02         PID25         1            499.00
```

As you can see, there are only 2 customers who have added items into their Cart. There are five items in `06's` shopping cart, and 1 item in `02's` shopping cart.

I'm thinking it would be better to put them into an array, instead of just adding and adding and adding. But, what about a list? Can you add a list to a DB Table? How would **you** add items to a "Cart"?

Comment: I think this approach is fine, it is nicely normalised. Why would you break this?

Comment: no need to change - this looks good as is. (except maybe use a number for the product_id)

Comment: Well, each day when I check out the table, it just looks really messy, I thought there might be a better way. But, I'm happy to stay with this, if there's nothing wrong with it. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost exactly how I would implement it, except that I tend to use GUIDs as keys.

However, you shouldn't store the price in that table; it can easily be calculated by multiplying the product price by the quantity.
If you allow custom per-user pricing, storing the price here might make sense, although it would still be better to store the information that led to the price.

Comment: Thank you very much, @SLaks. You're correct. I do have per-user pricing. If a user is a few (or 50) bucks short for a particular item or whole order, I'll discount them, that was my reasoning for adding the TotalPrice column.

Answer (score 0):

for a shopping cart, since there would be quite a bit of activity, I would use a NoSQL option, like MongoDB where you can save your C# objects http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial